# Having an error with my c++ classes project

Tags: c++

I am getting this error with my algorithm for adding fractions. 
The error is :
expected unqualified-id before ' _ 'token
Can someone explain me the meaning of this error. I looked it up online and didn't really understand anything.

### Rational.cpp

```
#include "Rational.h"
int main()
{
    Rational r1(1 ,2);
    Rational r2(1,4);
    r1.add(r2);
}

void add(const Rational&h2)
{
    int i, k;


}
```

Comment: Please show us "Rational.h". Also, please post the full error, including line numbers.

Comment: There are no `_` characters in shown code, so the problem is probably in `Rational.h` that you're not showing us.

Comment: So you've removed the code line that said "//error" and still don't give use any usefull information about where the error occurs or what file it is in.

Answer (score 3):

There should be:

```
Rational dem; // space instead of .
```

Comment: Oh ya. You have to write it like that so you can use dem thx.